# Self-join a table with the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join a table on itself, but on the next row (sorted by Empno).

Example data:

```
Empno  Work_hours  Max_Hours Empno
---------------------------------
1       5            7
3       6           12
4      14           16
```

I need to compare the data of each employee with the next employee.

I need the result like this:

```
Empno  Work_hours  Max_hours  Empno   Work_hours   Max_hours
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       5            7         3        6           12
3       6           12         4       14           16
4      14           16         NULL    NULL         NULL
```

I am working in SQL Server and I have tried multiple things using `ROW_NUMBER()` but I can't get the result as I described above.

Comment: What does "next record" mean? A table consists of _rows_ without any order.

Comment: Whilst this can be done, it raises a _LOT_ of questions, such as how will this information be useful to you? Please include some background on the analysis you are trying to perform, there is likely a much simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the correct output.

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTable
go
create table #tTable(
  Empno         int,
  Work_hours    int,
  Max_Hours     int);

insert into #tTable(Empno, Work_hours, Max_Hours) values
(1, 5, 7),
(3, 6, 12),
(4, 14, 16);
```

Query

```
select t.*,
       lead(empno) over (order by Empno) Lead_Empno,
       lead(work_hours) over (order by Empno) Lead_Work_hours,
       lead(max_hours) over (order by Empno) Lead_Max_Hours
from #tTable t;
```

Output

```
Empno   Work_hours  Max_Hours   Lead_Empno  Lead_Work_hours Lead_Max_Hours
1       5           7           3           6               12
3       6           12          4           14              16
4       14          16          NULL        NULL            NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(empno) over (order by empno),
       lead(work_hours) over (order by empno),
       lead(max_hours) over (order by empno)
from t
```

Comment: Note that Gordon wrote this before you updated your question from 'the next record' to 'the next row (sorted by Empno)'. As such, you would need to change the three `order by` statements to be `order by Empno`. This was the first answer and is reasonable for the original question but @SteveC's answer (which appears to be a copy and update of this answer) is more appropriate for the updated question.

Comment: @JcostKaal . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer, particularly after I fixed it based on the changes to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to suggest changing the accepted answer. Instead, to use Gordon's but note the additional change needed.